# Using CONVERT in a parameterised query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, parameterized-query

I have some java code that interacts with an Oracle database, and am converting it to work with SQL Server.

The code is:

```java
String parameterisedSQL = "INSERT INTO T(a,b) VALUES (?,?)";
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, databaseUser, databasePassword);
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(parameterisedSQL);)
{       
    stmt.setString(0,"test");
    stmt.setString(1,"CONVERT(DATE, '20201230', 112)");

    stmt.executeUpdate();
    return true;
}
```

Obviously when it was Oracle code, the code read `stmt.setString(1,"TO_DATE('20201230','YYYYMMDD')");`

The Oracle code against an Oracle database worked fine, but now I am running the SQL Server code against a SQL Server database, I get an exception

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I am assuming from this that SQL Server isn't parsing the CONVERT correctly as a parameter. Is there any way to get it to do this? (My code is actually more general than shown, so it would be hard to use `.setDate`, etc.)

Comment: Did you try to capture the query to check if your assumption is correct?

Comment: @HoneyBadger how would I do that in SQL Server?

Comment: Old school is using the profiler (available in SSMS, though not the newest version). The modern way is setting up an extended event.

Comment: I'm using an Azure database, and SSMS won't let me profile it

Comment: Parameters are strictly for adding values to a query not for inserting additional logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@forpas has given detailed answer.

Additionally, For your condition, you don't need to convert the short date format(ISO8601), before inserting to the table. You can directly insert.

[About ISO8601 date format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> ISO 8601  Description YYYY-MM-DD
>
> YYYYMMDD  Same as the SQL standard. This format is the only format
> defined as an international standard.

```sql
declare @TABLE table(T date)

insert into @TABLE (T) VALUES('20201230')

SELECT * FROM @table
```

for your case,

```java
stmt.setString(0,"test");
stmt.setString(1,"20201230");
```

Answer (score 2):

The way that you pass the function is interpreted like this:

```
INSERT INTO T(a,b) VALUES ('test', 'CONVERT(DATE, '20201230', 112)')
```

which is obviously wrong, because you try to insert the value `'CONVERT(DATE, '20201230', 112)'` in a `date` column.

You should do this:

```
String parameterisedSQL = "INSERT INTO T(a,b) SELECT ?, CONVERT(DATE, ?, 112)";
```

and:

```
stmt.setString(1,"test");
stmt.setString(2,"20201230");
```

The indices are 1 based.

Comment: @simonalexander2005 VALUES does not work with the statement as I wrote it. It needs different syntax. And I can't tell why it worked for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The question and both other answers are sub-optimal. You shouldn't send a date value to the database as a string. You should send it as a date value.

In this case, since it's a date-only value, without a time part, you would use `java.sql.Date` or `java.time.LocalDate`, depending on the capabilities of the JDBC driver.

Also note that parameter indexes are 1-base in the JDBC APIs.

```java
// Old code: Wrong
stmt.setString(0,"test");
stmt.setString(1,"CONVERT(DATE, '20201230', 112)");

// Using java.sql.Date
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
stmt.setString(1, "test");
stmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(fmt.parse("20201230")));

// Using java.time.LocalDate
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd");
stmt.setString(1, "test");
stmt.setObject(2, LocalDate.parse("20201230", fmt));
```

Comment: Ah yes, the indexing was my mistake typing the code here. As for the other options, I agree that this is technically the correct way to do it; but like I say in my question, my code is more general so I was trying to avoid using the different `.set` methods if I could. Thanks for giving the right way to do it though

Comment: Your answer is wrong. You can send a date value as a string to a database because all relational databases can convert strings to dates and SQL Server has more than 1 functions to do this job: CONVERT(), CAST, TRY_CONVERT() and TRY_CAST(). Converting strings to dates is common practice in SQL. Also, in SQL Server there is no need to convert a string like "20201230" to a date. It is accepted as it is so there is no need for java.sql.Date or java.time.LocalDate. Read Venkataraman R's answer. Also read my answer to see how easy conversion is done in SQL.

Comment: @simonalexander2005 this is not *technically* the *correct* way. This is just 1 way to do it. Also read my previous comment.

Comment: @forpas Guess I'm used to writing dialect-agnostic code. Sending a date value to the database as a string relies on RDBMS-specific functionality, but sending the value as a date object will work on all RDBMS's, because the JDBC driver will handle the dialect-specific differences.